# How to fix "ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned" warning?

Tags: assembly, memory-alignment, arm64

I start writing arm64 assembly code on M1 mac.
This is very simple sample code.

```
.global _main
_main:
    mov x0, #1
    ret
```

When I compile this code by clang, titled linker warning will displayed.

```
$ clang test.s
ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: _main from /var/folders/st/df0gjt9x5tl0cv7fw0xg5s9m0000gn/T/test-3c883c.o

$ ./a.out
$ echo $?
1
```

Generated binary is works well but how to resolve this linker warning?

Toolchain version (Xcode 12.3)

```
$ clang --version
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin20.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

---

After writing up this question.
write same behavior C file like this.

```
int main() { return 1; }
```

then output assembly code by clang

```
$ clang -S -O test.c
```

generated test.s file contains `.p2align 2`
If that is contained, warning will not displayed.

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .build_version macos, 11, 0 sdk_version 11, 1
    .globl  _main                   ; -- Begin function main
    .p2align    2
_main:                                  ; @main
    .cfi_startproc
; %bb.0:
    mov w0, #1
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ; -- End function
.subsections_via_symbols
```

Comment: You'd expect the text section to already be at least 4-byte aligned, but if you want to force alignment, obviously you can use `.p2align 2` or `4` in your own code.  That's why the compiler's using it.

Comment: Note you don't have a `.text` directive in your assembly source file.  I'm not sure what section is the default, but you should add it (before the `_main:` label) to be safe.  That could be the cause of the problem, if the default is some other section whose alignment is unknown.

Comment: hmm, linker warning will display even if add `.text` directive to line 1.

Answer (score 2):

As you observed the compiler doing, you need to add an alignment directive before each function symbol to guaruntee that symbol is emitted with a specific aligment.

You can use [`.align`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Align.html), [`.balign`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Balign.html), or [`.p2align`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/P2align.html) directives.

I personally have a weak preference for `.balign`; what you see is what you get. `.balign 4` will solve your problem. For `.p2align`, there's an implied 2^N for the first operand ('power 2 align'). In my experience `.align`'s behavior can be target specific, which is a mess in my opionion.

Here's a diff:

```
 .global _main
+.balign 4
 _main:
     mov x0, #1
     ret
```

Comment: `.balign 2` will align by 2 bytes.  You want `.p2align 2` or `.balign 4` like you wrote in the text of your answer.  Agreed that you should never use `.align`; it's `.p2align` on some GAS targets, `.balign` on others, so it's ambiguous for human readers with no benefit.

Comment: @PeterCordes you're correct (I got it wrong in the diff, not the textual response), thanks for noticing. I've updated my answer as a result.